# How secure are public cloud services like Skydrive, Google Drive, Dropbox?

Tags: internet, dropbox, cloud, onedrive, google-drive

I'm using Skydrive, Google Drive, Dropbox in my daily work for temporary file sharing.

About year ago, I lost all my private photos, videos, when my HDD totally stopped working. 
Now, I want to keep synced all my private stuff with these services for backup purposes but I really have fobia: probably someone else (for ex, service owner company's staff) will have access to my files.

Actually, there is some way: I can secure my files by encrypting them (and then syncing with cloud services) **but** it's very long and difficult process (especially if we're talking about 20-30 GB of photo)

The only real way is, to just sync folder (without any encryption) with these services. But in as I said, I have no trust to these services.

So any suggestions? Is there any kind of agreement that protects user right? Please explain your answer with facts.

Comment: Questions about web services and legal stuff are generally off topic for Super User. Please take a look at the **terms of service** and **privacy policies** of various providers and you will certainly find your answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the terms and conditions of the service carefully to see what they will do to your data, if you are considering trusting them with unencrypted data.  However, if the provider experiences a security breach, they may not be able to protect your data.  Likely there is a clause in the terms and conditions absolving them of any liability in this case.  You need to consult a lawyer to be sure.

Encryption is the only way to ensure no one else can do anything with the data once it leaves your property, as long as the keys are not compromised.